# Problem while generating table in PHP with wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to create my own custom theme in Wordpress.
Before that, I created a custom post type and now I want to show them into an array.

For that, I use AJAX and at this time, there is no problem.

The problem comes when I generate the table in PHP, the values of the recovered post are put anywhere.

Here my table generator:

```
  // Get paging system.
  $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

  // Create post request arguments.
  $args = [
    'post_type' => 'wp-lightnovel',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'paged' => $paged
  ];

  if (isset($_POST['season'])) {
    $season = $_POST['season'];
    if ($season != '' && $season != 'all') {
      $args['tax_query'] = [[
        'taxonomy' => 'wp-lightnovel-release-season',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $_POST['season']
      ]];
    }
  }

  // Ask for posts.
  query_posts($args);

  $content = '<table>';
  $content .= '<thead>';
  $content .= '<tr><th colspan="2">The table header</th></tr>';
  $content .= '</thead>';
  $content .= '<tbody>';

  while(have_posts()) {
    the_post();

    $image = get_the_post_thumbnail_url();
    $releaseSeason = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'wp-lightnovel-release-season')[0]->name;
    $postTitle = the_title();

    $content .= '<tr>';
    $content .= '<td><div style="width: 100px"><img src="' . $image . '" /></div></td>';
    $content .= '<td>' . $postTitle . '(<b>' . $releaseSeason . '</b>)</td>';
    $content .= '</tr>';
  }

  $content .= '</tbody>';
  $content .= '</table>';

  echo $content;

  die();
```

The problem is that the post title should be next to the release season but it's not the case as the render on the web:

[image: Screenshot of rendering on the web]

[image: Screenshot of rendering in the DOM]

I don't now is this happening.

If anyone has an idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Where you have `$postTitle = the_title();` change `the_title()` -> `get_the_title()` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/ or to `the_title("", "", false)` , `the_title()` echo's the title so that's why it shows before the content unless you set the 3rd param to false (the echo flag) - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title/ - will add an answer

Comment: It works nicely, thanks to you ! @SomeRandomPerson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are facing here is the following line;

```
$postTitle = the_title();
```

`the_title()` will echo the title of the post unless you set the 3rd parameter to be `false` as below [[docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title/)];

```
// 1st param = prepend | 2nd param = append | 3rd param = echo (bool true||false)
$post_title = the_title("", "", false);
```

You also have the option for `get_the_title()` [[docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/)];

```
$post_title = get_the_title();
```